# laravel created_at field is updating after update query

Tags: php, database, laravel-4

I've got 2 field `created_at`, `updated_at` they both are updating after I make an update query why that happens?

```
Table::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->update(array('is_new' => 0));
```

Comment: Is your table column `created_at` a timestamp that has the option to update the time on an update?

Comment: Thanks SamV that was my issue.